# pm2 process deleted itself, process no longer found

Tags: node.js, pm2

We have a process running on Node that killed itself 2 days ago. The following is from the pm2.log

```
2017-01-04 08:30:47: pm2 has been killed by signal, dumping process list before exit...
2017-01-04 08:30:47: Deleting process 0
2017-01-04 08:30:47: Stopping app:main id:0
2017-01-04 08:30:47: App [main] with id [0] and pid [32528], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
2017-01-04 08:30:47: [PM2] Exited peacefully
```

Restarting process 0 (which is no longer running) now returns:

```
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [0](ids: 0)
[PM2][ERROR] Process 0 not found
```

My understanding is that this is likely a memory issue. Any advice for restoring this process would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> 2017-01-04 08:30:47: Deleting process 0

means the process has been deleted entirely, so it can not actually be restarted. You need to start it anew with new process id.

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with the latest version. try version pm2 3.2.2. I hope it works for you.

```
npm uninstall -g pm2
npm install -g pm2@3.2.2
```